# set titles with name of days in fullcalendar plugin

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

In week mode, There is month/day title in x-axis label.. But I just want to name of day 
here is current view:
[image]

You see "Sun 3/6","Mon 3/7","Tue 3/6",.. I want these titles "Sunday","Monday","Tuesday".. Is there any way do this within plugin or I have to implement it manually

Comment: check this: http://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/axisFormat/

Comment: I am ıon it but it changes only time format, its fine for me I need to change days label format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [columnFormat](http://file:///home/chintan/web/extra_demos/fullcalendar-2.6.0/demos/agenda-views.html) in your calendar configuration.

```
columnFormat: 'dddd',
firstDay:1 // Monday as first day of week
```

Comment: Hello, Do you know how to change order of days.. It starts from "Sunday" but I want it start from "Monday"

Comment: Set firstDay:1 for Monday and firstDay:0 for Sunday.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution with using [columnFormat](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/text/columnFormat/) property.
it simple use only daynames with:

```
        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            //isRTL: true,
            axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
            columnFormat: "ddd",
            timeFormat: {
                agenda: 'HH:mm'
            },...
```